# Passing domain credentials to an ODBC connection attached to an access database using C# MVC 5 and IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ms-access, iis, odbc

I'm stuck with a problem where I am trying to query an access database that is located on our internal network using an ODBC connection to it. This works perfectly fine when running locally, but once you host the application onto IIS it no longer has access to the network folder that the database is stored in. Is there a way to use different credentials to access the folder other than the server's default?

Comment: You're trying to use ODBC to connect to a remote database hosted using IIS? That's not going to work.

Comment: How should I connect to the access database then?

Comment: Either use smb or iscsi. Any other solution is likely to fail. And even then, Access is not intended to be ran on a remote system, and if the connection isn't solid, it's likely to cause corruption.